# BUG, activity does not load fragment with firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase

my application so far is like this: in ActivityHome, it opens the Fragments using a "FragmentContainerView", my FragmentHome loads the firebase videos in a ViewPage2, using the design of an xml file

The problem is that after finishing the class files, the application does not run and presents the error in onCreate(Home.java), I could not solve the error or find the problem

Could someone point out how to solve this BUG?

layout/Activity_Home:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_inferior"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:maxImageSize="50dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#3f3f3f"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/nav_inferior"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_post" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/nav_inferior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_inferior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_inferior"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_bg"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_bg"
    />
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Home.java

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
ActivityHomeBinding binding;
private NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
private NavController navController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    IniciarComponentes();
    IniciarNavegacao();
    IniciarBadge();

}

private void IniciarNavegacao(){
    navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavInferior, navController);

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((navController, navDestination, bundle) -> {
        if (navDestination.getId() == R.id.nav_painel){
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = binding.bottomNavInferior.getBadge(R.id.bottom_nav_inferior);
            if (badgeDrawable != null){
                    badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
                    badgeDrawable.clearNumber();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void IniciarBadge(){
    BadgeDrawable badge = binding.bottomNavInferior.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.nav_painel);
    badge.setVisible(true);
    badge.setNumber(99);

    badge.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorError));
    badge.setBadgeTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, com.denzcoskun.imageslider.R.color.text_shadow_white));

}

private void IniciarComponentes(){
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_inferior);
    bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);

}
}
```

layout/FragmentHome

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/homeVideos"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragmente/FragmentHome.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
VideosConvert videosConvert;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ViewPager2 viewPager2 = binding.homeVideos;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<VideosDados> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<VideosDados>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Videos"), VideosDados.class)
                    .build();
    videosConvert = new VideosConvert(options);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(videosConvert);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    return root;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    videosConvert.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    videosConvert.stopListening();
}
}
```

layout/videoDesign

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/videoProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoTituloVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6.00sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7.80sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="15"
        android:text="Título"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoDescricaoVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="7.80sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46.8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20.80dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/calibri"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="15"
        android:text="Descrição do vídeo"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

VideoConvert.java

```
public class VideosConvert extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VideosDados, VideosConvert.myviewholder> {

public VideosConvert(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<VideosDados> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull VideosDados model) {
    holder.setdata(model);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_design,parent,false);
    return new myviewholder(view);
}

public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    VideoView videoView;
    TextView titolo,desc;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        videoView=(VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        titolo=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textoTituloVideo);
        desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textoDescricaoVideo);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoProgressBar);
    }

    public void setdata(VideosDados model) {
        videoView.setVideoPath(model.getUrl());
        titolo.setText(model.getTitle());
        desc.setText(model.getDesc());

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

VideoDados.java

```
public class VideosDados {

String desc,title,url;

public VideosDados(String desc, String title, String url) {
    this.desc = desc;
    this.title = title;
    this.url = url;
}
VideosDados() {

}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

after hours of failing to resolve, it seems impossible to resolve.
thanks for the time and help

Debug

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.meinlowe.souldiabah, PID: 30521
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.meinlowe.souldiabah/com.meinlowe.souldiabah.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.meinlowe.souldiabah:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #11 in com.meinlowe.souldiabah:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.meinlowe.souldiabah:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #11 in com.meinlowe.souldiabah:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.meinlowe.souldiabah:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 com.meinlowe.souldiabah.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding.homeVideos' on a null object reference
    at com.meinlowe.souldiabah.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:27)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2981)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:474)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1764)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2773)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1913)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:169)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2981)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:474)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1764)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.kt:158)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:53)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:274)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at com.meinlowe.souldiabah.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(ActivityHomeBinding.java:56)
    at com.meinlowe.souldiabah.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(ActivityHomeBinding.java:50)
    at com.meinlowe.souldiabah.Home.onCreate(Home.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4009)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Is it an exception? Please update your post including the error/exception

Comment: @JornRigter when I run, the application just closes, so I added DeBug with the error that appears

Comment: This is not a bug, but your XML seems to be invalid. `FrameLayout` is not a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: In `HomeFragment`, `onCreate` is called before `onCreateView` - so the binding object is not set yet. You need to move the stuff out of `onCreate` to somewhere later in the [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) where the binding was already defined.

Comment: @TylerV thanks for the lesson, I made the change in the position of the objects in fragmenteHome.java and the application started perfectly (it didn't load the video but it opened again, which is already amazing) I will continue to study